# Delay and recurse

Tags: c#, task

I'm trying to write a function that will test some condition and return a value, but if the condition isn't satisfied, it will wait and then try again. I could, of course, just throw in a `Thread.Sleep`, but I thought I ought to be able to pull this off with tasks and `asynch` / `await`, but I can't quite hit of the right syntax to make this work. For example:

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(TimeSpan waittime)
{
    if (someCondition) 
    {
        return SomeFunctionThatReturnsValue<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return await Get<T>(waitime);
    }
}
```

Works, but doesn't have any delay (obviously), so I've tried multiple variations like this:

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(TimeSpan waittime)
{
    if (someCondition) 
    {
        return SomeFunctionThatReturnsValue<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return await Task.Delay(waittime).ContinueWith(t => Get<T>(waitime));
    }
}
```

But this give me the compile time error:

`Error  52  Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'T' rather than 'Task<T>'`

I can change the last `return` to this:

```
return await Task.Delay(waittime).ContinueWith(t => Get<T>(waittime).Result);
```

And it compiles, but that doesn't seem exactly right either.

Comment: Try removing the `await` - it causes your current function to actually wait until the task is executed.

Comment: Why not just call `await Task.Delay` then `return await Get<T>(waitime)` in your else block?

Comment: You should really be using a `while` loop, not recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want your method to be asyncrhonous, when you want to get the result of a `Task` you should use `await`, not `Result`, so that the action is performed asynchronously, so you can write that operation as:

```
return await await Task.Delay(waittime).ContinueWith(t => Get<T>(waitime));
```

Alternatively, whenever you have two awaits you can use `Unwrap` instead; it's not really better or worse; it's equivalent:

```
return await Task.Delay(waittime).ContinueWith(t => Get<T>(waitime)).Unwrap();
```

Note that by using `Unwrap` you could also make the method not be `async` and not `await` it because `Unwrap` is already doing the job of turning your `Task<Task<T>>` into a `Task<T>`.

Of course, you generally shouldn't be using `ContinueWith` in an `async` method for the most part, you should simply be using `await` to attach continuations to your tasks:

```
await Task.Delay(waittime)
return Get<T>(waitime);
```

It's also worth noting that you should really be using a `while` loop here, rather than using recursion, particularly because you have an `async` method which means building *another* state machine for every single recursive invocation.

Comment: Makes sense. `await await` wasn't something I thought of doing. And `Unwrap` is new on me. But yeah, just `await`ing the delay makes the most sense. And the tip of using `while` instead makes sense too.